# why is this function outputting a word multiple times instead of one?

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>//needed to make string array
#include <fstream>//Needed for redaing in from external file
#include <cstdlib>//needed for rand() function (for random word)
#include <ctime>//needed for time() funtion to seed rand()
using namespace std;

void wordPick();
int main()
{
    wordPick();

    return 0;
}

void wordPick()//reads in external file and puts it in an array for a library of words to randomly choose
{
    char secretWord;
    srand(time(0));
    ifstream inFile("randwords.txt");
    if(inFile.is_open())
    {
        string wordlist[10];
        for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
        {
            inFile >> wordlist[i];
            srand(time(0));
            string secretword = wordlist[rand() % 10];
            cout<< secretword << endl;
        }
    }
}
```

my program is supposed to take a random word from an external file list and output it one time but instead, it is basically writing over the rest of the list with the chosen word.

This is for a game of Hangman that the user will have to guess so it needs to be only once. Can anyone help its due in 3 days.

Comment: did you intend to put the `string secretword = wordlist[rand() % 10];` outside of the loop instead?

Comment: You have a loop and in the loop a `cout`

Comment: Move `srand(time(0));` to the beginning of your program. Having it in the loop resets the seed every iteration so that you get the same number every iteration.

Comment: You have also an unused variable: `char secretWord`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move this:

```
srand(time(0));
string secretword = wordlist[rand() % 10];
cout<< secretword << endl;
```

outside of your `for` loop, and remove the redundant call to `srand(time(0))`:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
{
    inFile >> wordlist[i];
}

string secretword = wordlist[rand() % 10];
cout<< secretword << endl;
```